# Which design pattern is suitable for converting relational data to a domain model?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

### Problem

I have some code which turns data stored in relational form to a domain model. The source is not an RDBMS, but a set of generated 'table' classes. These table classes are comparable to a `java.sql.ResultSet`, each representing one set of data: orders, ordered items, deliveries, invoices, serial numbers.

The conversion code creates a hierarchy of domain models from scratch by iterating over the tables. It creates appropriate model objects, hooking them into other model objects and so forth. Once finished, it returns the domain model (a list of orders).

The problem is that the conversion code is all shoved into one class and covers different aspects of the data, so it's really hard to unit test, find bugs or extend it. I need to maintain this code for years and really want to split it up somehow, but I'm unsure as to which design pattern might apply nicely here.

### Idea

I'm leaning towards refactoring the code into the visitor pattern:

- introduce a container class that exposes references to the table objects (e.g. `getOrdersTable()`, `getOrderItemsTable()`)
- create multiple visitor classes for this container class. Each visitor covers one aspect of the source data: one that creates the order objects themselves, another creating the delivery objects and hooking them into the respective order objects, and so forth.

I am, however, unsure about the following **issues**:

- the visitors would not only work with the table objects they visit, but also with objects created by other visitors (where the latter are all accessible by the order list which is the root of the domain model). Thus, the order in which visitors are invoked is important.
- The visitor pattern is often explained in the context of node hierarchies, but I would not have them *visit* a hierarchy, they would *create* one.

### Questions

1. Is Visitor a good choice, or would you choose another well-known pattern? Or is this a case where no design pattern applies really well and I should avoid (mis)using pattern terminology?
2. Is any of the **issues** above unusual for visitors? If so, do you think implementing Visitor anyway would make the code confusing? After all, patterns are about matching intuitive expectations and improving the meaningfulness of code.

### Context info

- I can safely add methods to the table classes (each consists of an abstract generated class and a subclass intended for manual modification) or have them implement interfaces, but cannot modify their common superclasss or introduce a new one.
- The set of tables is relatively stable, but new columns will likely be added. Also, there is some degree of change in the conversion logic itself (e.g. which orders to skip, or special cases for mapping data)
- The domain model itself is relatively clean, I have no intention to change it in non-backwards-compatible ways or even replace it entirely.
- This is about Java code.
- Thread safety is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already I suggest you get a copy of Martin Fowler's book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa)

The visitor patterns as you say is really a pattern for applying an operation to objects already put structured in some way - as you say you're not there yet.

In Martin Fowler's terminology I think what you want is a [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) which is similar to  your current implementation.

For me the trick is to make sure your implementation is written with maintanibility and testability in mind.  You may want to practice some TDD to help you achieve your goals but in summary I think your should look at what functionality can be separated out into 'helper' classes which can be unit tested simply

For example you may decide to have a Data Access Object for each 'table' leaving the main DataMapper class to control the final construction of the Domain Model

Answer (score 0):

Domain Object  or Business Object Pattern will suffice your need.

Please go through Business Object
http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/BusinessObject.htm

Domain Store  Pattern if you application is more complex in nature

http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/DomainStore.htm